# Nested routes in NestJS are confused with parameters

Tags: rest, routes, nested, nestjs

I am trying to implement a NestJS API with the recommended REST API structure, where I am facing a problem with nested routes.
Let's say we have `school` and `class` modules. But each of these modules have also corresponding `type` modules. School types can be elementary, high school etc. Class types can be seminar, lecture, lab course etc. Therefore, I have 4 modules (school, class, school types and class types). According to [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/rest-api-best-practices-rest-endpoint-design-examples/), I should use nested routes for more clarity on related resources. Therefore I want to have the following routes:

```
/school(/:id) // to get all schools or school by id
/school/:id/type // to get the type of school by id
/school/type // to get all school types
/school/type(/:id) // to get school types or school type by id
/class(/:id) // to get all classes or class by id
/class/:id/type // to get the type of class by id
/class/type // to get all class types
/class/type(/:id) // to get class types or class type by id
```

To keep my code tidy, I have subfolders for school-type and class-type modules to keep things tidy.
As docs suggest, I am using [router-module](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/router-module):

```
imports: [... SchoolModule, RouterModule.register([{
    path: 'school', 
    module: SchoolModule, 
    children: [
      {
        path: 'type',
        module: SchoolTypeModule
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'class', 
    module: ClassModule, 
    children: [
      {
        path: 'type',
        module: ClassTypeModule
      }
    ]
  }]),
```

When running NestJS, logs suggest that the desired routing is in place. Shown for school only:

> LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/school/:id, GET} route +0ms

> LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/school, GET} route +1ms

> LOG [RoutesResolver] SchoolTypeController {/api/school/type}: +0ms

> LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/school/type/:id, GET} route +1ms

> LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/school/type, GET} route +1ms

> LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +6ms

The problem is that when I try to access all school types, api/school/type routes to api/school/:id
I wonder, what I am missing. I know that static routes need to come before the dynamic ones but school/type is whole different submodule in it's own controller.